# Error en Segue "Show", no permite ir atrás. Xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

Buenas. Les comento, tengo un proyecto que desarrollé con Xcode 8 y todo funcionaba bien, ahora he estado realizando unos ajustes con Xcode 9 y me he percatado de un bug que antes no me sucedía, el cual tiene que ver con un segue que realizo. Tengo una pantalla principal, la cual tiene el como Título: "Inicio", esta tiene algunas asignaturas de la universidad, la idea es que cuando presiono una de ellas se me despliegan los detalles de este a través de un nuevo Navigation View Controller que tiene además una segunda vista a partir de un Segue tipo Show, garullada al presionar en el botón "Asistencia", una vez presiono el botón, me dirijo a esta vista pero no me permite volver a la primera vista, sino que sigue apareciendo el botón para volver al menú "Inicio" ("Atrás").

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código lo tengo de esta manera. Al presionar uno de los elementos, llamo a la vista "detalleClase", el cual comienza con un nuevo Navigation View Controller. Este se estructura como está en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, no se si se provocará por lo mismo, pero una vez que salgo de ese menú, y vuelvo al "Inicio", con:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los títulos de los distintos menús de la aplicación dejan de aparecer:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sinceramente he intentado de todo, pero no puedo dar con la solución. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

En la función atrasButton, intenta con dismissViewController ya que siempre estas mostrando otro ViewController, en lugar de ocultar el que la tienes.